# Как удалить div при нажатии на ссылку в jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как в jquery удалить div с классом .tab-wrapper при нажатии на ссылку с классом .tab-link ??

```
<div class="tab-wrapper">Контент</div>
<a class="tab-link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По клику находим и удаляем:

```js
$('.tab-link').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.tab-wrapper').remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrapper">Контент</div>
<a class="tab-link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! А не подскажите еще как сделать, чтобы div плавно исчезал с анимацией?

Comment: @АндрейКурусь Сначала присвоить какой нибудь класс с анимацией, дождаться выполнения, потом удалять из DOM

Comment: @АндрейКурусь $('.tab-wrapper').hide(() => $('.tab-wrapper').remove())